# Can I use the "function" command to call certain rows of a dateframe?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe containing species presence/absence data across many sites. This is a basic representation of what it looks like.

```
df=data.frame(site=c("site1","site1","site1","site2","site2","site2"),
           speciesA=c(0,1,0,1,1,0),speciesB=c(0,0,0,1,0,1),speciesC=c(1,0,1,1,1,1))
```

I'd like to be able to work on specific sites individually (aka specific rows with the same name in the site column).

I'm able to use subset to isolate one site.

```
subset(df[df$site=="site1", ])
```

I tried to use a function to do this for all sites without writing out the full code,

```
sitename<-function(s){
   subset(df[df$site=="s", ])
}
sitename(site2)
```

But this returns <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names).

Comment: Don't put quotes around `"s"`. `s` is an R object that you've defined as a function argument. `"s"` is a string with the letter 's' in it.

Comment: Also, you are mixing 2 different subset syntaxes. It works, but is unnecessary and could lead to bugs. You can use either `subset(df, site == s)` or `df[df$site == s, ]`, you don't need to mix them together (and it's probably a bad idea to do so).

Comment: NOTE: from [`?subset`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/subset.html): *"This is a convenience function intended for use interactively. For programming it is better to use the standard subsetting functions like `[`, and in particular the non-standard evaluation of argument ‘subset’ can have unanticipated consequences."*. I can confirm that it is not too difficult for programmatic use of `subset` to fail, sometimes silently.

Comment: But what is interesting about your use is that your call to `subset` is doing nothing: the `subset=` argument is not used, and the `select=` argument is not used, so your use of `subset(.)` is completely an identity function (with overhead).

Comment: I'm voting that this is a typo. Perhaps not technically, but perhaps it's more of a learning moment: in R, the literal string `"s"` will "never" refer to the value of the function argument unless it is passed to something that knows to look for it, such as `get` or `mget`, or in `\`[\``, or `\`[[\`` as column-selectors as in `df[, "s"]` (which is not what you want, granted). Since you're using it as an argument to the infix `==` operator, you are looking for the literal `"s"` (regardless of what the `s` variable holds).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of subset here is a bit redundant because you are indexing the data frame as well. You should either use

```
sitename <- function(s){
   subset(df, site==s)
}
```

or

```
sitename <- function(s){
   df[df$site==s, ]
}
```

along with

```
sitename("site1")
```

Comment: The redundancy is not the reason why the code is not working. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have your input variable inside quotation marks. In addition, you should use the quotation marks when passing your input. Try the following:

```
sitename <- function(s){
   df[df$site==s, ]
}

sitename("site2")
```

**Edit:** As noticed by others, `subset()` here is completely useless.

Comment: `subset` is doing nothing here, and should not be used programmatically. This should work exactly the same with just `df[df$site==s, ]`.

Comment: Agree, but the use of subset was not the cause of problem. It's not needed, but it works. In any case, I removed it.

Comment: I agree that the redundancy is not the problem, frankly I think this answer explains the real issue while both answers fix it. I think it's either a typo or a programming-learning-moment, where `=="s"` != `==s`, as you highlighted. Hope the OP realizes the practical takeaways, and perhaps learns about the `subset`-caution.